# Can someone explain the logic behind these expressions used to calculate nonorthogonal collisions?

Tags: physics, processing

I'm following an example in a Processing book describing how to calculate nonorthogonal collisions (a ball bouncing on a non-horizontal plane), however, I don't really understand the logic behind these four expressions.

```java
 float groundXTemp = cosine * deltaX + sine * deltaY;
 float groundYTemp = cosine * deltaY - sine * deltaX;
 float velocityXTemp = cosine * velocity.vx + sine * velocity.vy;
 float velocityYTemp = cosine * velocity.vy - sine * velocity.vx;
```

They're supposed to be calculating temporary values for the ground coordinates and velocity of the ball to calculate the collision as if it were orthogonal. Cosine and sine are the values for the rotation of the ground, and the velocity variables are the velocity of the ball. I can't grok what the expressions are actually doing to make the ground horizontal, and the book doesn't explain it very well. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These expressions are traditional expressions of a rotation. If you take a point (x,y), and you rotate it by an angle theta, you will obtain a point (x',y') with coordinates :

x' = cos(theta)*x - sin(theta)*y
y' = sin(theta)*x + cos(theta)*y

In your case, let's say that theta is the angle of the ground, you want to do the inverse rotation (so with angle -theta) to make the ground horizontal, this is why the sign is different from the formula above (cos(-theta) = cos(theta) and sin(-theta) = -sin(theta)).

If you want to go into details, check : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Comment: That clarifies a lot, but I still don't understand why the rotated Y value is being added to the x value and the rotated x value subtracted from the Y value.

Comment: In a rotation you always (expect in trivial cases) have mixing of coordinates. A drawing of the situation should make you see it, from the same drawing and elementary trigonometry, you can derive the whole formula.